# Excel date query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a cell at the top of the spreadsheet that contains the date (say Feb 2013). I want to create columns off of that "reference" cell. In other words, based off of that date, I want one of the columns to display. But when I attempt, this it simply does not auto-increment the date but displays some random date.

02/01/2013
02/02/2013
02/03/2013
..
..
02/28/2013

Comment: Are you trying to do this via a formula or via dragging the cell down?

Comment: `I want one of the columns to display` ...what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

As far as excel is concerned, a date in excel is just a number incremented from some arbitrary day in the past. For example, type `2/5/2013` into any cell. Excel will automatically format this cell as a date. Now right click, and format the cell. Under the number tab, select general and you will see excel really has the date stored as `41310`. Using this same principle, if you want to increment dates based off of a reference date, it can be done simply by `=A1+1` assuming the reference date is in cell `A1`. For example, type `2/1/2013` in cell `A1` and in column `B` type `=A1+1`. Now drag this cell down as far as you want. As long as column `B` is formatted as a date, it will increment day by day.